# filter and range with map are not working

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

my need is to go over a list but extract only the first two elements out of that list.

i wrote the following code

```
payload.list.*listItem filter ($.type == "supervisor") map {

// other code

}
```

this worked perfectly fine. Then I modified it to extract the first two elements only like this

```
payload.list.*listItem filter ($.type == "supervisor") [0 to 1] map {

// other code

}
```

and it doesnt work anymore. i am getting no error but the other code doesnt work as if the map operator has nothing to go over.

also i need to make it work for a scenario if there is only one element after the filter is applied.
how should i change my code to make this work.

Comment: Please add the input and expected output.

Comment: And also add your complete dataweave script including above the '---' as well as what version of dataweave you're using.

Comment: Would be in your best interest to post the question with sample input and expected output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range selector must be used directly over an Array so you just need to properly do the selection:

```
(payload.list.*listItem filter ($.type == "supervisor"))[0 to 1] map {

// other code

}
```

Comment: but thats what i did.  it doesnt give me any error during deployment but it blows out in runtime. Also if the output of filter is only 1 element will [0 to 1] still work or will it kind of throws an out of index error.... ?

Comment: Have you tried it? I think @afelisatti used parenthesis to ensure the range selector is being applied to the right value.

Comment: If the output of the filter is only 1 element, the [0 to 1] selector will return null. In this case, you can use an If statement to check the size of the return of the filter (I would create a variable for that filterOutput) or use default [filterOutput[0]] after the range selector (if the selector returns null, it will select the first element of the filterOutput)

Comment: i completely overlooked the additional pair of () around. apologies. it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parenthesis to ensure precedence.  Also, I'm surprised it worked for you at all.  I needed to put "type" in single quotes to get it to work since that is a dataweave keyword.  I did this `?($$<2)` instead of `[0 to 1]` since I wasn't sure if you were guaranteed to have at least two objects in the output of the filter.  If you know, you'll have at least two, leave it the way you had it.

```
(payload.list.*listItem filter ($.'type' == "supervisor"))[?($$<2)] map (value, index) -> 
    {
        "key":value
    }
```

Here's a [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-flow-control-precedence#:~:text=) to Dataweave documentation on precedence.  It snags a lot of people.  Safer just to use parens in most cases.